# SVG SMIL animations removed when used in a symbol?

Tags: html, svg

I have an animated svg ([like you can see here](http://jxnblk.com/loading/)) which works when inlined... however when i convert the svg into a symbol so i can access it anywhere with xlink:href... browsers seem to strip out the animate tags from the svg.

SVG inlined: http://puu.sh/cLkTR/24db186e78.png

SVG symbol reference: http://puu.sh/cLkZ7/51051612d3.png

Couldn't find any documentation on if this is the expected behavior, so asking here to see if anyone knows. Thanks :)

EDIT

Here is a snippet of the svg "sprite sheet" as requested. http://pastebin.com/3tUYueCj

And this is how it is included in html:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="sprites.svg#icon-loading.spinning.bubbles"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Without seeing your source code - I'd suggest wrapping your icons in the <symbol> element. This looks like you're using the <g> element.

Comment: I've updated the post with a sample of the svg sprite sheet and how its used in HTML

Comment: After some more testing, though, it looks like this is a bug in Chrome's implementation... as in Firefox, this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Chrome 38 if the symbols are defined in the same document as the use element (see snippet below).

Are you using an experimental version of Chrome?  I am not seeing a "shadow root" definition for the use element in the Chrome DOM inspector -- that might be something new that is creating unexpected bugs.  SVG use elements are not directly equivalent to web component shadow roots.  You'll want to file a bug report if you haven't already.

```css
svg.defs {
  height: 0; width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

svg.icon {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<svg class="defs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 32 32" id="icon-loading.spinning.bubbles">
        <title>loading.spinning.bubbles</title>
        <circle cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(45 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.125s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(90 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.25s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(135 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.375s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(180 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.5s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(225 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.625s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(270 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.75s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(315 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.875s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
      <circle transform="rotate(180 16 16)" cx="16" cy="3" r="0">
        <animate attributeName="r" values="0;3;0;0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0.5s" keySplines="0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8;0.2 0.2 0.4 0.8" calcMode="spline" />
      </circle>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-loading.spinning.bubbles"/></svg>
```

Comment: Nah, i just have the option to show shadow doms turned on :). Looks like this is a Chrome bug that occurs when you use external svgs sadly.